# How to run "npm run start" from release pipeline Azure DevOps to start production build in NUXTJS?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I want to create CI/CD for my nuxt application to deploy it on windows server. I have done all the things like copying files, npm install, npm run build. But the last step is to start the server by npm run start command and after running this command nuxt will show some related information like port no. etc and the command remains in the executable form (non-terminated command).
So when I run it from my pipeline the task is not terminating because of it.
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/commands#production-deployment

I had tried different little hacks like

- Created batch file and run it as Power-shell command from start-process command
- Open new cmd window to execute npm run start and close the previous one from this command "start cmd /k echo npm run start"

Answer (score 0):

I use pm2 (it's free, https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to daemonize nuxt on production servers. It works very well with nuxt and it respawns the process if for some reason crashes. That way you will exec a command on startup that will launch nuxt as a daemon in the background, but the command will terminate... that may solve your issue I think.